# Swift - Using custom classes as cells in a TableView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to display a list of movies in a TableView using Swift. Basically a Movie object has a title, rating, genre, etc.

Here's the Movie.swift class

```
class Movie {

enum Genre { case scifi, romance, thriller, drama }

var title: String
var genre: Genre
var rating: Int

init(title: String, genre: Genre, rating: Int){
    self.title = title
    self.genre = genre
    self.rating = rating
}
```

In my ViewController.swift code I have this to hold the list of Movie objects

```
var movies = [
    Movie(title: "Citizen Kane", genre: Movie.Genre.drama, rating: 10)
]
```

When I try to run it the code stops here

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let row = indexPath.row

    // When I try to open the view with the TableView the code breaks in this line
    cell.textLabel?.text = movies[row].title
    return cell
}
```

I'm pretty new to Swift and iOS development in general so I'm not sure where I went wrong. Let me know if I need to post more code. Thanks!

Comment: Tried to run your code - it worked. But I wouldn't recommend using `let cell = UITableViewCell()`. Use `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` instead

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a cell use the method:

```
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)) as UITableViewCell
```

the method creates a new cell for the given row or reuses an existing one (for making the scrolling smoother)

The **"CellIdentifier"** is the identity you give to your custom cell in the storyboard

Make sure you implement the `UITableView` delegate methods for creating the correct number of rows so you won't overflow your movies array which might also cause a crash in your case

There is an example [here](https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/) for a simple table view implemenetation in swift